# GLSL - Deactivating vertex shaders for color selection

Tags: glsl

We're studying color coding picking in GLSL for an assignment.
We're also using a vertex shader which change the colors of the objects we would like to pick.

Given a boolean indicating weither or not we are in picking mode (let's call it `selectionMode`), how can I make sure the shader doesn't influence the color while we're trying to pick an object?

I was thinking about transferring the boolean to our vertexShader.glsl file, and change the operations we apply on each fragment based on the value of the boolean. Is it correct? Is there an easier way?

**EDIT**

Sorry if it wasn't so clear. I'll try to explain myself better. The issue boil down to this:

- In `main.cpp`, we define that when the user right click on the screen, we check for the color of the pixel underneath the mouse cursor and select an object accordingly: if it's 255 0 0 we select the cube, if it's 0 255 0 we select the sphere, etc.
- In vertexshader.glsl, we apply a formula so the color of an object change according to its position. So when we render the scene, the cube is not alway 255 0 0, the sphere is not alway 0 255 0, etc.

How can I solve this contradiction?

Comment: How would the shader *influence* the color ?

Comment: The question is not really clear so I'm not sure what you are wondering, but you might want to have a look at GLSL subroutines to change the behaviour of your shader (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Subroutine)

Comment: I tried to explain it better in my edit.

Comment: I guess you should add some code, that would clarify stuff ^^